# grey screen, that appears for 7 second, when changing background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a [webite](http://david.addagio.cz/gospel), on that website, 3 images are changing every 7 seconds, in 3 laps.

Code:

```
var swap;
function run(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;

    function func() {
        document.body.id = "b"+int;
        int++;
        if(int === frames) { int = 1; }
    }

    var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

run(7000, 3);
```

and the second half (i don't think the problem is there.)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    //... your logic goes here...
    $("body").css("background-image", "background-image: url(1.jpg)");
    if(youWantToStopTheInterval){
        window.clearInterval(swap);
        $("body").css("background-image", "background-image: url(1.jpg)");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#b1 {
    /* Location of the image */
    background-image: url(1.jpg);
    /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
    background-position: center center;
    /* Background image doesn't tile */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content's height is greater than the image's height */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
    background-size: cover;
    /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
    background-color: #464646;
}
#b2 {
    /* Location of the image */
    background-image: url(2.jpg);
    /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
    background-position: center center;
    /* Background image doesn't tile */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content's height is greater than the image's height */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
    background-size: cover;
    /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
    background-color: #464646;
}
#b3 {
    /* Location of the image */
    background-image: url(3.jpg);
    /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
    background-position: center center;
    /* Background image doesn't tile */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content's height is greater than the image's height */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
    background-size: cover;
    /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
    background-color: #464646;
}
```

Now, if we refresh, or load, the page, there is grey in the background (for no reason I can see), that is here for 7 seconds...(than, it is all perfect) why? / How to fix it?

Comment: The first wait it because you don't change the image until the first 7 second interval has elapsed. You should change the image first, then set the next interval.

Comment: Looks like it takes forever to download a 900kb image too, is this a cheap server? You may want to look into this.(checked on Firebug "net" tab)

Comment: @Dan White It is not any cheap server... yeah, i will check it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you should execute the function prior to setting the interval to set the initial image which is why you see that blank for 7 seconds.

Also you will never see all the images because you increase the `int` variable and then check to reset it before that value can be used. You should change your if check.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/5f566hrc/

```
var swap;
function run(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;

    function func() {
        document.body.id = "b" + int;
        int++;
        if(int > frames) { int = 1; }
    }
    func();
    var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

run(7000, 3);
```

All that aside, changing the ID of an element in order to pull this off seems hacky to me. This isn't perfect, there are probably better ways to do this but using classes is still better than changing element IDs over and over.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/5f566hrc/1/

```
var swap;
function run(interval, frames) {
    var int = 1;
    var previousClass = "";

    function func() {
        if (previousClass != "") {
            document.body.classList.remove(previousClass);
        }
        previousClass = "b" + int;
        document.body.classList.add(previousClass);
        int++;
        if(int > frames) { int = 1; }
    }
    func();
    var swap = window.setInterval(func, interval);
}

run(7000, 3);
```

CSS:

```
.b1 {
    ...
}
.b2 {
    ...
}
.b3 {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you think, that changing classes is better? :)

BTW, the best solution is mentioned in comments, i did not have set background-color now it works great for me... but the image loading is killing me!!! :)

Comment: Well I think its better to use a class because changing the ID of an element every 7 seconds in order to apply CSS seems wrong. Take advantage  of how CSS works and use a class.